# Safe way to resize an instance of System.Span<T> and System.ReadOnlySpan<T> (C# language)

Tags: c#, memory, .net-core

This should be a very easy and quick answer for the experts and, maybe, the reason for which I didn't found anything on the web.
Supposing that a span buffer is insufficient to store the required data, this is what I do to resize...

```
    public static void Resize(this ref Span<byte> span, int newSize, bool preserveContent = false)
    {
        if (preserveContent)
        {
            var newSpan = new Span<byte>(new byte[newSize]);
            span.CopyTo(newSpan);
            span = newSpan;
        }
        else
            span = new Span<byte>(new byte[newSize]);
    }

    public static void Resize(this ref ReadOnlySpan<byte> span, int newSize, bool preserveContent = false)
    {
        if (preserveContent)
        {
            var newSpan = new Span<byte>(new byte[newSize]);
            span.CopyTo(newSpan);
            span = newSpan;
        }
        else
            span = new Span<byte>(new byte[newSize]);
    }

    // Usage:
    MyReadWriteSpan.Resize(100, true);
    MyReadOnlySpan.Resize(100);
```

It works as expected, but I am wondering if mine is the correct implementation and/or there could be any downside like unneeded allocations or whatever. If someone has a better implementation I would really appreciate. I tried to reuse code by writing an overload where one of the two calls the other, but unfortunately Span and ReadOnlySpan does not seems interchangeably:

```
    public static void ResizeReadWrite(this ref Span<byte> span, int newSize, bool preserveContent = false)
    {
        SpanExtensions.ResizeReadOnly(ref span, newSize, preserveContent);
    }

    public static void ResizeReadOnly(this ref ReadOnlySpan<byte> span, int newSize, bool preserveContent = false)
    {
        if (preserveContent)
        {
            var newSpan = new Span<byte>(new byte[newSize]);
            span.CopyTo(newSpan);
            span = newSpan;
        }
        else
            span = new Span<byte>(new byte[newSize]);
    }
```

**Error: CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref System.Span' to 'ref System.ReadOnlySpan'**

If someone have an idea I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Span` and `ReadOnlySpan` are not classes but structs, and more importantly, they don't implement any interfaces and don't inherit from each other. That's why you can't reuse your code like what you tried in the last code sample.

The problem I'm seeing in your code is when you try to shrink a Span and preserve its data. In this case, `CopyTo` call throws an ArgumentException, which is better than lost data. But I believe this is something your code should anticipate and handle because otherwise, it seems an unintentionally hidden bug.